# Using $a_{\overline {n} \rceil i}$ from Exam FM.

Tags: finance, actuarial-science

I am trying to solve the following problem

> Olga buys a 5-yr increasing annuity for $X$. Olga will receive $2$ at the end of the first month, $4$ at the end of the second month, and for each month thereafter the payment increases by $2$.  The nominal interest rate is $9\%$ convertible quarterly.  Calculate $X$.

Below is my attempt. I did not use the formula for the special case where P=Q=1 but I chose to use the general formula. But I got the different answer and I don't which step had the problem

$j = \left(1+\tfrac{.09}{4}\right)^{1/3}-1  \approx 0.007444$.

$X = Pa_{\overline {n} \rceil j}+Q*\frac{a_{\overline {n} \rceil j}-nv^{n}}{j}$

$X = (P+\frac{Q}{j})a_{\overline {n} \rceil j}-Q\frac{nv^{n}}{j}$, using the TVM calculator

I got $X = 13068.1656-10304.2044=2763.9612$, which is close to answer C: 2780
But the correct answer is B: 2730

Comment: I get $X=\sum_{n=1}^{60} 2n(1.0225)^{-n/3}=2729.2143$.  Something must have gone wrong before that, as you should have $Qnv^n/j=(2)(60)(1.0225^{-1/3})^{60}/j=10329.5813$ for example.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using $(I^{(m)}a)^{(m)}_{\bar{n}|}$ to solve for the present value of an annuity where payments increase monthly](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4521292/using-imam-barn-to-solve-for-the-present-value-of-an-annuity)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$P=Q=2\\
j\approx.007444\\
a_{\bar{n}|j}=\frac{1-1.007444^{-60}}{.007444}\approx48.25\\
nv^n=60\times1.007444^{-60}\approx38.45\\
X=\color{blue}{(2+2\div.007444)\times48.25}-\color{green}{2\times38.45\div.007444}\\
\approx\color{blue}{13060}-\color{green}{10330}=2730$